# Custom WP_Query for current category (in category.php)?

Tags: categories, wp-query, tags

I'm using a small code to display a tag list for the current categories like below:

```
<?php
$custom_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1&category_name=overnachten');
if ($custom_query->have_posts()) :
while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            $all_tags[] = $tag->term_id;
        }
    }
endwhile;
endif;

$tags_arr = array_unique($all_tags);
$tags_str = implode(",", $tags_arr);

$args = array(
'smallest'  => 12,
'largest'   => 12,
'unit'      => 'px',
'number'    => 0,
'format'    => 'list',
'include'   => $tags_str
);
wp_tag_cloud($args);
?>
```

It currently displays the tags used by the posts in one certain category. I want to use the above code to display all the tags from the category I'm currently in. How would this be possible, with the above code or a better way?

Comment: Can I ask what the purpose of this is? It sounds like this is a problem you have with a solution to yet another problem that you haven't mentioned, and that there may be a far better/faster/easier way to do what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 8):

Try referencing the [cat query variable](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars#Query_variables) like so:

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'cat' => get_query_var('cat') 
    ) 
);
```